# Finding tuple with maximum difference between its minimum and maximum first element

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hashtable

Given an array of elements of the form (a,b) where a is an integer and b is a string. 
The array is sorted in terms of `a` the first element. We have to find the `string b` 
which has the maximum difference between it's lowest a and highest a.

**My Thoughts :**
A simple approach is to hash each string to a HashTable ensuring that no two same strings
map to the same hashtable. Now consider any bucket for a string `b` we need to store only 
two two elements in that bucket one the max a encountered till now and one the min a encountered 
till now. Once the hashtable is populated we simple have to iterate over all strings and 
find the one with the maximum difference.

Now this could run in O(N) time 
But the only questionable assumption here is that the strings will go into a different bucket
That cannot be guaranted simply by any implementation of HashTable while maintaining the
average time complexity of insert, search  and delete to be Theta(1)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: 1) What will be the average time complexity of this approach ? 2) As I am assuming that hash table will hash elements to different Is that feasible?

Comment: It will be Theta(n) for best-case and average-case, and Theta(n^2) worst-case. Hashtables have amortized complexity of Theta(1) for all basic operations.

Comment: "A simple approach is to hash each string to a HashTable ensuring that no two same strings
map to the same hashtable." - you don't really need that. Usually hash maps allow for some hashes to collide. Anyway, I'm not sure what you're asking about. In any language you have pretty decent implementations of hash maps that indeed work in a expected constant time. You have to keep in mind that you also have to calculate the hash, that probably takes time depending on the length of the string. The complexity is indeed expected O(N), where N is a sum of lengths of the strings.

Comment: Usually in the hash maps, the hashes do collide. For each hash you keep the linked list of elements with that hash. Then if you get a specific hash, you iterate through the linked list for that hash and check for the element. The only thing is that the collisions should be rare, so there aren't many things in the linked list. That's actually not that hard to satisfy, you just have to use a good hash function.

Comment: Is average case complexity same as amortized complexity ?

Comment: No, it's not. Amortized analysis can be combined with best-case, worst-case or average-case assumptions about the distribution of the inputs. In this case I assumed an average-case distribution to get Theta(1). For worst-case amortized complexity you would get Theta(n^2).